# DHCP Sending gateway address ending in .0

Tags: networking, router, dhcp, wireless-access-point, ipv4

My in-room router (*which i have set up as an access point*) is connected to another main router downstairs managed by the home owner. Im calling the main one router A and the one in my room router B. Router B has DHCP turned off, as router A provides the actual internet connection to the house and manages the DHCP for the building.

Now every room is assigned its own IP pool/subnet where room 1 for example has an ip range of 192.168.*1.x*, room 2 has 192.168.*2.x*, etc. Mine happens to be 4. I also set up a wireless access point (lets call it router C) connected to router B because router B has no wifi capability and the wireless access point only has 1 LAN port.

In this moment, the gateway (aka router A) for me is 192.168.4.1 and router B has a static 192.168.4.2, router C has a static 192.168.4.3. They both have 192.168.4.1 as standart gateway set, as .0 was not allowed. Here comes the weird part.

When i connect wireless devices to my router C they get a standard gateway of 192.168.4.0, which my iphone for some reason cannot interpret and gives up saying no internet. 192.168.4.0 is accessible from my phone and it yields router A's homepage. I checked out my windows computer which is connected to router B via cable, and it also has picked up a gateway of 192.168.4.0, but here i do have internet. This is not just an iphone thing as another android device which connected to router C recently had the same result.

The only fix i found for the affected devices would be to manually set them a static IP just to fix the standart gateway problem. The only way i have found to recieve internet.

I ran a tool to find DHCP servers, and found only one, the main router, so there is no rouge DHCP in play.

My question is, is it possible to force devices connected to either router B or C to have a standard gateway sent out to them of 192.168.4.1?

Comment: Don't over complicate it, switch your router to `router` mode and plug WAN port to the home network. Adjust your router such way it is not conflict with primary home's gateway (set your LAN to 192.168.88.0/24 for example) and turn DHCP on your router. You would have your own private, protect from others local network. Set WAN port to automatic mode ( get IP from primary DHCP gateway)

Comment: What is the subnet mask on these devices?

Comment: @Appleoddity on all it is 255.255.255.0

Comment: @Alex is that a viable solution? I would mess up the whole network as i would be running a secondary dhcp server on the network, and others could get wrong information coming from my router.

Comment: No, you wouldn't mess network if you switch your router in `router/firewall mode` instead of access point . DHCP would work on your side only, serving your LAN network only. You router would be visible for others as a single device but you, on your side (LAN) can add as many devices (including additional access points) as you need. Extra positive point, - is that home owner devices wont's see what is on your internal LAN (because of firewall). Just think about home owner gateway as it is a normal internet provider.

Comment: @Alex thank you for the quick response. Ill give it a try and keep you updated. I had such a thing before, but the dhcp server was serving from 19.168.1.0 to 52 and everything was working fine until leauge of legends started having major problems then i reverted to this config which made it work again. Probably i needed to set the dhcp server to server from 192.168.88.0 or something what you said.

Comment: Yes, the only important thing is that your LAN network must not be in a range of networks that can be on WAN side. If your router allows to set any private networks on LAN side, then make it 10.23.45.0/24, it much less chances of collision than on 192.168.x.x.

Comment: Also note that with @Alex solution that there will be a double NAT setup. Which could cause (more)issues with port-forwarding and such in regard to UPnP++ - Still, it's a viable solution if you don't mind the double-NAT; and it seems to be better than getting served a .0 address as GW from the DHCP!

Comment: @Alex The solution worked perfectly. Devices are now assigned the correct gateway (router B) and leauge of legends is having no trouble reaching the servers. Thank you once again!

Comment: No problem, Im glad to help you. I moved my comments to the actual answer, so in case some1 would be in the same situation like yours then may be my advice would be useful too.

Comment: I’m glad it’s all working now. But on a side note, have you thought about having the core router fixed so it stops giving out the wrong gateway address? Should’ve been fairly simple. Someone probably just made a typo or misunderstood how it works.

Comment: @Appleoddity I guess core router is doing it on purpose. It's common setup to separate tenants in rented homes by splitting them in subnetworks to isolate from each other that makes "good" security from owner's point of view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't over complicate it, switch your router to router mode and plug WAN port to the home network. Adjust your router such way it is not in conflict with primary home's gateway (set your LAN to 192.168.88.0/24 for example) and turn DHCP on your router. You would have your own private, protected from others local network. Set WAN port to automatic mode (get IP from primary DHCP gateway).

You wouldn't mess up existing network if you switch your router in router/firewall mode instead of access point. DHCP would work on your side only, serving only your LAN network. You router would be visible for others on WAN side as a single device, but you, on your side (LAN) can add as many devices (including additional access points) as you need. Extra positive point, - is that home owner devices wont's see what is on your internal LAN (because of firewall). Just think about home owner gateway as it is a normal internet provider.

The only important thing is that your LAN network must not be in a range of networks that can be on the WAN side. If your router allows to set up any private networks on LAN side, then make it 10.23.45.0/24, it's much less chances of collision than on 192.168.x.x